# python zip file hit userwarning: Duplicate name

Tags: python, zip

I have a python script that exclude the folder and zip the rest into zip file. However my script zip all the files in the same directory level

it gives the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py:1505: UserWarning: Duplicate name: '1.txt'
  return self._open_to_write(zinfo, force_zip64=force_zip64)
C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\zipfile.py:1505: UserWarning: Duplicate name: '2.txt'
  return self._open_to_write(zinfo, force_zip64=force_zip64)
```

the folder structure to be zip

```
-test
 -file1
   -1.txt
   -2.txt
 -file2
   -1.txt
   -2.txt
 -dump
 -file3
```

My python script

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from datetime import date
from os.path import basename

# format the dd/mm/y 
today = date.today()
todayDate = today.strftime("%d-%m-%y")

# path to zip
pathZip = "C:\\PY\\Project\\Self\\python-zip\\test"
# get the final forler name
forlderToZip = basename(pathZip)

# format the zip file name
zipFileName = todayDate + " " + forlderToZip + ".zip"
# create a ZipFile object
zipObj = ZipFile(zipFileName, "w")
# exclude the folder to be zip
exclude_folder = "dump"

print("Zip start...")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(pathZip):
    if exclude_folder in subdirs:
        subdirs.remove(exclude_folder)
    # Add empty folder to zip
    zipObj.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        # create complete filepath of file in directory
        filePath = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        # Add file to zip
        zipObj.write(filePath,basename(filePath))
        print("Zip " + filePath)
# close the Zip File
zipObj.close()
print("Zip done !")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate name warning comes from the input directory files, of the same name, all being written to the same place of the output zip. The below get overwritten and you are left with two text files in the zip.

```
-Output Zip
    -1.txt
    -1.txt
    -2.txt
    -2.txt
```

The arcname argument is expanded below to retain the nesting structure of your original directory. The arcname arg modifies the name and placement of a file when writing to a zip. The 'if continue' is used to skip child files with 'dump' in their path.

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

path_to_dir = ''
path_to_zip = ''

output_zip = ZipFile(path_to_zip, "w")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_to_dir):
    if 'dump' in dirpath:
        continue
    for f in filenames:
        outpath = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        arcname = outpath[len(path_to_dir):].lstrip(os.sep)
        output_zip.write(outpath, arcname)
output_zip.close()
```

```
-Output Zip
    -folder1
        -1.txt
        -2.txt
    -folder2
        -1.txt
        -2.txt
```

Alternatively, rename the files from the original directory such that they are unique. One way to do this is by replacing backslashes in the arcname path.

```
arcname = outpath[len(path_to_dir):].lstrip(os.sep).replace('\\', '_')
```

```
-Output Zip
    -folder1_1.txt
    -folder1_2.txt
    -folder2_1.txt
    -folder2_2.txt
```

For more info see [nested directory appear while creating zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424402/nested-directory-appear-while-creating-zip-file)